# Contour approximation containing undesired points

Tags: opencv, polygon, shapes, approximation

Hi there i have a polygon problem. I don't know what to look for so i decided to ask here. The image below shows a simple shape. The contours are detected with OpenCV's [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) and aproximated by the [CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS](http://www-prima.inrialpes.fr/perso/Tran/IEEE-PAMI/1989/Teh89-PAMI.pdf) (for those who want to know how this is done) algorithm, so that all points in a line, are summarized to a single line.
So anyways some contours contain some sort of, i call it noise, in the shape. The image below shows what is meant with noise. The red line is the contour. (Sorry no ms paint skills)

[image]

My goal is to redefine the shape to approximate the shape, but leave out this "noise". So the contour should look like this. The blue line shows the corrected contour.

[image]

Comment: Did you check [cv::approxPolyDP](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-approxpolydp)? It looks like it's doing what you are trying to achieve. If you have steep angles you might need to apply the function partially and not at the whole polygon at once.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'll give feedback in a few minutes

Comment: Well no luck with cv::approxPolyDP

Comment: What result does it produce? Wrong polygon?

Comment: The result snuggles to the contur not ignoring the noise

Comment: I just checked the algorithm behind [cv:approxPolyPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm) it's more for smoothing a series.

Comment: Hm... I thought trimming the epsilon parameter would be enough to give a decent result. Sorry I wasn't helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Try to detect corners with...`cvGoodFeatuersToTrack()`....but have a criteria that corners should be separated by a good amount of distance...if corners form a cluster discard them.
2. From the list of points that are in the contour...choose the point with (highest x, highest y), (highest x, lowest y), (lowest x, highest y) and (lowest x, lowest y)....now join these four points...
3. If you have 'noise' at the corners itself then try to detect straight lines in the image using Hough's transform...

Comment: This sounds quite useful, but what if my polygon is not a simple rectangle; something like a L shaped polygon? (I'll update my question quick)

Comment: What is the chance that you can have 'noise' at the 90 degree corners?

Comment: Close to zero. BTW very good approach searching for clusters! +1

Comment: then go for 1st approach...I think it will be easy...!!

Comment: Okay, I'll implement it quick

Comment: Clustering nerby points solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I can propose one more approach:

1)You can use [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to detect lines on your image (before use Canny to detect contours). You can not take into consideration small lines by using rather big threshold (the minimum number of intersections to “detect” a line) in method  HoughLinesP.

2) After finding all lines you can find their intersection as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042397/i-am-struck-at-finding-the-point-of-intersection-of-most-lines-in-an-image) by @DanielHsH. So you will be able to find all corners.